# How to use transpiled js file from webpack in node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, transpiler

I am trying to use a library written in typescript/es6 in a node.js application that is not in typescript. I use webpack to transpile the library to js. The output of the transpiled file  looks something like this (Not the exact library, but basically exporting a method to consume when I require it) :

```
!function(e){var t={};function r(n){if(t[n])return t[n].exports;var o=t[n]={i:n,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[n].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,r),o.l=!0,o.exports}r.m=e,r.c=t,r.d=function(e,t,n){r.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:n})},r.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},r.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=r(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var n=Object.create(null);if(r.r(n),Object.defineProperty(n,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var o in e)r.d(n,o,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,o));return n},r.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return r.d(t,"a",t),t},r.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},r.p="./",r(r.s=0)}([function(e,t,r){e.exports=r(1)},function(e,t,r){"use strict";t.getName=()=>{console.log("name")}}]);
```

When I require this in my node.js application, I am not able to use the method that was exported.

So if the above code was in a file called, bundle.js and I do the following

```
const testFunc = require('./bundle.js')
testFunc.getName()
```

I get an error that says testFunc.getName is not a function.

How would I be able to access the getName method from the transpiled js file?

Comment: Can you try logging testFunc in the console to verify getName is available?

Comment: @colecmc testFunc is an empty object {}. My question is how do I use bundle.js to access the getName method?

Comment: So if testFunc is an empty object, then there is no getName method and you cannot access it. Perhaps `./bundle.js` exports it directly, like this `require('./bundle.js').getName` maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either. I get require(...).getName is not a function

Comment: I don't think ./bundle.js is exporting anything. Is it in the node_modules dir?

Comment: @colecmc even when I put module.test = ''!function(e){var t={};...'' I am still not able to access ''getName''